# Number of ways to sample a specific number of objects from a collection with several types of objects.

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to figure out the following combinatoric problem:

**Simple case:** Suppose I have $N$
  objects of two types with sizes $i_{1},i_{2}$
. I sample $n\leq N$
  objects without returning, how many ways are there to sample $0\leq l_{1},l_{2}\leq n$
  (where $l_{1}+l_{2}=n$
 ) objects of each type? This is of course equivalent to the number of ways to sample just $l_{1}$
  objects of type $i_{1}$

**General case:** Suppose I have $N$
  objects of $2\leq k\leq N$
  types and in each type the number of objects is $0\leq i_{j}$
  such that $\sum_{j=1}^{k}i_{j}=N$
 . I sample $n\leq N$
  objects without returning, how many ways are there to sample $1\leq l_{j}\leq i_{j}$
  objects from each type (where $\sum_{j=1}^{k}l_{j}=n$
 ).

**Note:** The title doesn't really describe the question well, if anyone has an idea for a better title feel free to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $l_j$ are given, and you're not counting order?  Then you're asking for how many ways to choose
$l_1$ objects out of the $i_1$ of type $1$ and $l_2$ objects out of the $i_2$ of type $2$ and ... and $l_k$ objects out of the $i_k$ of type $k$.  These choices are independent.  So the answer is
$$ {i_1 \choose l_1} {i_2 \choose l_2} \ldots {i_k \choose l_k} $$

If that's not what you were looking for, please clarify your question.

Comment: Yep, that is really super simple, I'm not sure why I got so messed up with this... Counting problems have never been my strong suit. Thanks!